# Modifying an xlsx file using Java POI API

Tags: java, excel, api, apache-poi

I need to modify an existing xlsx document by appending some contents at last which has to be done by java. I am using POI.jar for doing this but the problem is every time its create a new excel file (i am able to create and read a excel file using POI).Anybody please help me to do this. Give me some sample code for appending vaules into the existing excel file.Also please suggest me any other API is available for doing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post existing code that you have trouble with.

Comment: Why don't you use xlsx file as the datasource of your application. It will work as you want

Comment: What exact problem are you having? Are you saving to a new file, or trying to overwrite the existing one? Are you sure you're loading in the original before making changes?

Answer (score 0):

Write your new file to a temp filen, rename the old one with a .bak extension (or whatever), rename the new one to the right file name, and then you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for alternative API's, I thought I'd mention [Officewriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-api.aspx). It's .NET though, not Java, but it's pretty swanky. As a disclaimer, I'm totally partial since I'm one of the engineers who built the latest version.